# Line breaks when using tikz package {er,positioning} in simple entity-relationship diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking

The following code does *exactly* what I want, with the exception that I would like line breaking. Ideally, I want the numbers to appear under the word 'Thing' but there will be other text as well. The usual suggestions of using `tabular`, or the general use of '\\' do not work, probably because I am using the `er,positioning` package.

First post, so please let me know if I need to change or adjust anything to suit the usual rules here.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{er,positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{nopageno}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=1.5cm]
\node[entity] (node1) {Big Idea}
[grow=up,sibling distance=5cm]
child[grow=left,level distance=5cm] {node[attribute] {Thing 1}}
child {node[attribute] {Thing 2}}
child {node[attribute] {Thing 3}}
child {node[attribute] {Thing 4}}
child[grow=right,level distance=7cm] {node[attribute] {Thing 5}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't know what you tried exactly, but all the usual things seem to work fine, e.g. `node[attribute,align=center] {Thing\\2}` or `node[attribute] {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Thing\\3\end{tabular}}`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I didn't have ```align=center``` in there. That did it. Thank you for helping with my silly issue. If you want to post a short answer, I will upvote and accept it.